# foreach array function storing in a variable?

Tags: php, arrays, variables

```
 $numbers = array('1','2');
 $numberlist = foreach($numbers as $number) {
      echo $number;
 }
```

As you can see what I'm trying to do it doesn't work is there any other way to store a foreach function as a variable?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: is that `$` in front of the echo a typo in the question? Because that will not work :)

Comment: I think Matthew is trying to store a procedure or function into a variable. But for starters you'll want to remove the $ in front of 'echo'. Then see the answers below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$numberList = function( $input )
{
    foreach( $input as $v )
        echo $v;
};

$numberList( $numbers );
```

See [PHP Anon](http://us.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

> **Note:** Anonymous functions are available since PHP 5.3.0.

(The function should be $numberList with a capital L in order for it to work properly.)

Comment: this only works if you have the newest version of PHP (5.3.x)

Comment: I'm using 5.3.5;
I used the example you've given me and the variable seems not to be outputting?

Comment: @Matthew, I assume you passed in an array when you called the anon function (see last line of example)? Also, that array should contain strings or numbers only. Arrays, booleans, and nulls may print nothing :P

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to store a code reference to the foreach loop in the `$numberlist` variable, that can't be done: loops are not functions.

If you want an object you can cycle on, you need to build an interator. If this is the case, I suggest you take a look at [Standard PHP Library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.spl.php).

Answer (score 1):

I think what Matthew is trying to do is store a function in a variable in PHP. I think this link is what you're looking for:

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php